# Heroku app requested endpoint API not found

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, flask

I pushed a very basic Python Flask app to Heroku but the index page does not load. Error is

> The requested API endpoint was not found. Are you using the right HTTP
>   verb (i.e. `GET` vs. `POST`), and did you specify your intended
>   version with the `Accept` header?

status.heroku.com does not show any known problems at this point. Though not necessary, I added `methods = ['GET']` above index method, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened once a year ago. That was a heroku free tier issue( https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1404 ). Now https://status.heroku.com shows that it has no known issues with API's.

So, the first thing you can do is to clear the heroku cache by running-

```
heroku repo:purge_cache -a your_heroku_app_name
```

If that doesn't work, you can try the other options[1] below-

- Clearing the cache using https://github.com/heroku/heroku-builds#purge-build-cache (which does a more thorough cache-clear for Ruby buildpack projects)
- Checking that your deploys are pushing the correct branch to Heroku (it only builds what's being pushed to master, so pushing another branch won't take effect)
- Filing a support ticket if none of the above works (https://www.heroku.com/support)

[1]https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo/issues/86#issuecomment-427694374